# How to customize MPVolumeView in iOS?

Tags: ios, slider, volume, mpvolumeview

I need to make a custom thumb for my volume slider, which I need it to be a MPVolumeView. Is there any way I can change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: note that in iOS 6, there are built-in methods for customizing the MPVolumeView slider, similar to the methods for UISlider:

```
- (void)setVolumeThumbImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
- (void)setMaximumVolumeSliderImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
- (void)setMinimumVolumeSliderImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can only customize UISLider:

```
[slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderThumb.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```